# Sort rows (or columns) of a matrix in Python 3

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, matrix

I have this code wrote in Python 3.3 to input a matrix:

```
matrix = []
loop = True
while loop:
    line = input()
    if not line: 
        loop = False
    values = line.split()
    row = [int(value) for value in values]
    matrix.append(row)
```

I'm trying to find a way to be able to sort either the columns or the rows of the matrix, without using numpy. I tried this:

```
matrix = zip(*matrix)
matrix.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

But it doesn't work at all. And also for example the row or column would be sort with a sort algorithm like:

```
inc = len(list) // 2
while inc:
    for i, el in enumerate(list):
        while i >= inc and list[i - inc] > el:
            list[i] = list[i - inc]
            i -= inc
        list[i] = el
    inc = 1 if inc == 2 else int(inc * 5.0 / 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the rows directly using `sort`:

```py
>>> matrix = [[9, 1, 8], [2, 7, 3], [6, 4, 5]]
>>> sort(matrix)
array([[1, 8, 9],
       [2, 3, 7],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```